# Is there a way to convert an hour string to a Time type in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm creating a 24 hour dropdown with 30 minute increments for a set time when someone wants to arrive at a destination and was wondering is there a good format to use and how do you convert it to type Time (since I am storing it in the database as a Time type).

These are the options I am using:

```
  def options_for_hours_select
    [
      ['4 AM','4'],
      ['4:30 AM','430'],
      #etc
    ]
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using 30 minute increments, you could change use numeric option values, like this:

```
def options_for_hours_select
  [
    ["4 AM", 4],
    ["4:30 AM", 4.5]
  ]
end
```

then, when you want to convert it to a time, you can just add that many hours to the start of the day, (ActiveSupport makes this particularly easy) e.g.:

```
Date.today + 4.5.hours # gives 4:30AM today
```

and if you have two parameters `:date` and `:arrival_time`, you could combine them like this:

```
time = params[:date].to_date + params[:arrival_time].hours
```